# Continue with values until the next key from a list while reading lines from a file - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator

I have a list of values like this:

```
names_needed = ['PCC', 'PSP', 'ASP']
```

Also, I have `.txt` file I am reading from to extract some values based on the above list:

```
PCC WITH NOTHING
ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18
ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17
KUCHEN,SARA null V00011 03/21/19 

PSP SECONDARY
MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19 
ACOSTA,AD null V00010 06/19/17 

PCC WITH SOEMTHING
BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19 
BECE,COR null V00010 10/25/16 
TORRE,M null V0001143 06/06/19

ASP HAS IT
XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19

PSP Wanted
NICK,SON null V00011 05/20/19
JUARE,SABIO null V00011 04/02/19
```

From this text file, I want to read in each line and then check if one of the key values is present and put all data into a list after that key word.

Something like this:

```
PCC:
[ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18
ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17
KUCHEN,SARA null V00011 03/21/19 
BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19 
BECE,COR null V00010 10/25/16 
TORRE,M null V0001143 06/06/19]

PSP:
[MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19 
ACOSTA,AD null V00010 06/19/17 
NICK,SON null V00011 05/20/19
JUARE,SABIO null V00011 04/02/19]

ASP:
[XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19]
```

The result can be a list of lists, or it can be a dictionary of values. I tried the following:

```
names_needed = ['PCC', 'PSP', 'ASP']

## Key word list
key_word_list = []

## Empty list to save all lines
all_lines = []

## Open text file
read_text_file = r'text_file.TXT'

### Open the file
with open(read_text_file) as f:
    # For each line
    for line in f:
        # Strip off white space characters
        stripped_line = line.strip()

        # Iterate the list of key values   **** HERE is WHERE I AM ITERATING KEY WORD
        for i in names_needed:
            if i in stripped_line:
                key_word_list.append(i)
                all_lines.append(stripped_line)

            else:
                break
```

This is not giving me the results I want. I can't seem to get to the lines between current key word and next key word.

Comment: what is the point of `each_line = line.split('\n')[0]` if you're going to strip the line immediately after anyway?

Comment: I don't see how that's possible when you iterate line-by-line in Python

Comment: Have you tried replacing your for loop with the readline(), or readlines() methods?

You could read in the whole file into a list of separated lines using the readlines() method. Then a for loop for going over each line, a nested for loop for key-matching, and then use list.insert at the current element/index of the line to insert the lines you want.

Comment: @plum0 no, I did not try that. Good suggestion, I will try and get back to you.

Comment: It is a bit inefficient, as you will read every line from the file into a list, and then you search through the list (meaning you are running through the same information twice and can be cumbersome), but bruteforce then optimize is the approach I typically tend to take.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I edited the post for your convince :) Hope this helps now!

Comment: Thanks. That was really a minor nitpick, but I appreciate you fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

A different way to approach this problem is to identify which lines contain a key, and append all the following lines to the corresponding key in a dictionary. Your file lends itself well to this solution since key lines, for example, don't have a slash anywhere in them:

```
def is_key(line):
    return '/' not in line
```

The output will be in the form of a dictionary, mapping each key to the list of lines that belong to it:

```
keywords = {key: [] for key in names_needed}
```

Now you can use these definitions  as follows:

```
key = None
with open(read_text_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if is_key(line):
            key = line.split()[0]
        elif key in keywords:
            keywords[key].append(line)
```

You can access `keywords` by key now:

```
for key, lines in keywords.items():
    print(f'{key}:')
    print(f'    {"\n    ".join(lines)}')
    print()
```